# Runnable, Pause and Resume thread

Tags: java, android, runnable, onresume, onpause

my app is working fine but i cant figure out why my void run(); still runs in the background when i click the "home" button.

I want my thread to pause the Thread onPause and start the thread again when onResume() i called!

Cant figure out what im doing wrong!

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Thread thread;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    thread = new Thread(new MyThread());
    thread.start();

}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    this.thread.interrupt();

    Log.d("Method:","OnPause();");



}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    this.thread.run();
    Log.d("Method:","onResume();");

}


@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    this.thread.interrupt();
    finish();
    Log.d("Method:","onDestroy();");

}
```

}

Inner class:

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
            if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){

                break;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d("Method","void run()");
            //Creates a file with SharedPreferences and make editable
            SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrime", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

            Random random = new Random();
            BigInteger bigInteger = new BigInteger(10,random);

            //Loads and gets the last int value store in the file
            SharedPreferences preferences1 = getSharedPreferences("MyPrime",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            final int numberInFile = preferences1.getInt("MyPrime",0);

            if(bigInteger.isProbablePrime(random.nextInt(500))){
                if(numberInFile < bigInteger.intValue()){
                    editor.putInt("MyPrime",bigInteger.intValue());
                    editor.commit();

                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're catching and ignoring the `InterruptedException` that gets thrown when you interrupt the thread. Don't ignore exceptions!

If you take a look at [the relevant docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()), you can see that if you interrupt a thread while it's waiting in a `sleep` call, that exception will be thrown and the interrupted status will be *cleared* (i.e. `isInterrupted()` will return false). And your thread probably spends most of its time in that sleep call so it's likely it gets interrupted there.

Comment: Thank you! That workded! I just learnd something about exception! :)

I change the catch statement to:
`try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                   Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }`

Answer (score 0):

Remove code from onCreate and make your onResume work like so.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    thread = new Thread(new MyThread());
    thread.start();
    Log.d("Method:","onResume();");
}
```

Comment: This didnt solve anything, void run() is still running every 1 sec in logCat

Comment: @Spoofy Well in the onPause you need need to kill the thread.  Set a Boolean variable or whatever you are used to doing.  and have your thread check on that variable to decide whether or not to keep looping